# Windows 10 загружается только до логотипа

Tags: windows

Была проблема с обнаружением диска в дисководе, пытался решить.

Нашёл информацию в интернете о том, что нужно отключить одну функцию(возможно DMA, конкретно не помню)в диспетчере устройств во вкладке IDE ATA , во всех Channel (у меня их было 4 , два нулевых и два с единицей)

перезагрузил комп и загрузка не идёт дальше логотипа

очень благодарен любой помощи[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Походу обнову поймали.... Через безопасный режим войдите в систему и откатитесь до рабочего состояния, или удалите то, что установили последнее.

Comment: я через безопасный не могу войти, тоже не прогружает

Comment: @АвгустДи,  тогда наверное переустановка и сразу после неё системный backup